# Having trouble implementing spring boot actuator custom health indicator

Tags: spring-boot, health-monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

I've tried to follow the documentation, but I only see "status : UP" every time I check. I even went as far as to return Health.down.build() universally, but I still just see "status : UP". I'm not sure what I've done wrong. I have no errors.

Comment: Have you checked that your custom `HealthIndicator` is being called? How have you added it? Perhaps you can share some code that shows what you've tried thus far?

Comment: Simply called with: "MyCustomHealthIndicator myCustomHealthIndicator = new MyCustomHealthIndicator(); myCustomHealthIndicator.health();" Do I need to create a Health object of my own?

Comment: Your `HealthIndicator` needs to be a bean. Is it a bean?

Comment: My health() method already has the \@Override annotation (as is shown in the example in the documentation), so are you saying I must add the \@Bean annotation or must I define it as a bean myself in an xml file?

Comment: It needs to be a bean so you either need to return an instance of it from a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class, or you need to annotate the class with `@Component`. There's an example of the latter [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_writing_custom_healthindicators)

Comment: That's exactly how mine is set up, so I'm guessing health() somehow is never being called. I'll look some and update the question as necessary

Comment: Does a builder need to use what is returned by the health() method in order to display the correct information at http://localhost:8080/health [like in the diskspace healthindicator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/DiskSpaceHealthIndicator.java), or should a freestanding call to health() alone in the code 'update' what is output at health endpoint? Do I need to set properties for the endpoint? I've turned off sensitivity and security, so I can see db and diskspace but still not mine.

Comment: I really think you should share some code that reproduces the problem you're having. It's very hard to understand what you're doing otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom `HealthIndicator` is registered on the go if you add the `@Component` annotation to your class. 
If you then call the method *actuator/health* I guess you're getting the summarized status:

```
{"status":"DOWN"}
```

Just add this to your *application.properties* to see a detailed view of the `HealthIndicator` result:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

and you will get something like this:

```
{
"status": "DOWN",
"details": {
    "MyCustomHealthCheck": {
        "status": "DOWN",
        "details": {
            "remote.system.down": "There is something wrong with system XXX"
        }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "details": {
            "total": 499963174912,
            "free": 434322321408,
            "threshold": 10485760
        }
    }
}
```

}